# responsive issue on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a website which must be responsive for mobile phones. I've created it using my desktop. When I adjust browser windows it's working perfectly for mobile phone but when I check it on my real mobile phone: HTC E9 it's not responsive to the mobile view.i have use wordpress please give the solution

Comment: have you added viewport in your html head?? i.e. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: yes but its not working on htc E9

Answer (score 0):

which framework are you using "BOOTSTRAP 3.0" and simple media query. and 
Check meta tags also in your headers those support mobile platform:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

use this css also :-

```
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title> responsive layout </title>


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can use this markup for responsive and use media query `@media (min-width:1600px) and (max-width:3600px) {` according to media screen  .

Comment: @-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}  where add this code

Comment: in css add @media (min-width:1600px) and (max-width:3600px) {   } for responsive or other .